# Jmeter - JSON response manipulation Append node in ArrayList

Tags: arrays, json, jmeter

I've got the response from HTTP GET request as JSON object and I want to use that JSON and put other node pass it to the next HTTP request. I got the following response data

```
{
  "settlementFolio": "0002",
  "settlementID": 283,
  "businessUnitID": 43,
  "routeID": 955,
  "chargeAmount": 22248.0000,
  "paymentAmount": 68560.6000,
  "isPaid": false,
  "hasValidCrewConfiguration": true,
  "settlementDate": "2020-09-21T00:00:00",
  "charged": 68560.6000,
  "packageRemain": 7500.0000,
  "totalBoxes": 280,
  "detail": [
    {
      "settlementTransactionID": 1,
      "settlementTransactionDescription": "1 Ventas Netas",
      "charge": 0.0,
      "payment": 61060.6000,
      "isAutomatic": true,
      "isForClient": false,
      "isCharge": false,
      "isChecked": false,
      "settlementTransactionClientDetail": [
        {
          "settlementTransactionID": 3456,
          "clientID": 392342,
          "saleNote": 11792,
          "amount": 30530.3000,
          "reference": "",
          "clientName": "OXXO NUEVA MAYAPAN",
          "isChecked": false
        },
        {
          "settlementTransactionID": 3456,
          "clientID": 391322,
          "saleNote": 11793,
          "amount": 30530.3000,
          "reference": "",
          "clientName": "OXXO CHICHI SUAREZ",
          "isChecked": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "productTypeCounter": [
    {
      "centralCostID": 1,
      "centralCostName": "Refrescos",
      "sellUnit": 280,
      "cNomina": 0.0000
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to append a node like this with  "settlementTransactionID": 2,

```
{
  "settlementFolio": "0002",
  "settlementID": 283,
  "businessUnitID": 43,
  "routeID": 955,
  "chargeAmount": 22248.0000,
  "paymentAmount": 68560.6000,
  "isPaid": false,
  "hasValidCrewConfiguration": true,
  "settlementDate": "2020-09-21T00:00:00",
  "charged": 68560.6000,
  "packageRemain": 7500.0000,
  "totalBoxes": 280,
  "detail": [
    {
      "settlementTransactionID": 1,
      "settlementTransactionDescription": "1 Ventas Netas",
      "charge": 0.0,
      "payment": 61060.6000,
      "isAutomatic": true,
      "isForClient": false,
      "isCharge": false,
      "isChecked": false,
      "settlementTransactionClientDetail": [
        {
          "settlementTransactionID": 3456,
          "clientID": 392342,
          "saleNote": 11792,
          "amount": 30530.3000,
          "reference": "",
          "clientName": "OXXO NUEVA MAYAPAN",
          "isChecked": false
        },
        {
          "settlementTransactionID": 3456,
          "clientID": 391322,
          "saleNote": 11793,
          "amount": 30530.3000,
          "reference": "",
          "clientName": "OXXO CHICHI SUAREZ",
          "isChecked": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "settlementTransactionID": 2,
      "settlementTransactionDescription": "2 Envase Faltante",
      "charge": 0.0,
      "payment": 7500.0000,
      "isAutomatic": true,
      "isForClient": false,
      "isCharge": false,
      "isChecked": false,
      "settlementTransactionClientDetail": [
        {
          "settlementTransactionID": 3461,
          "clientID": 0,
          "saleNote": null,
          "amount": 7500.0000,
          "reference": "202|75.00|100.000",
          "clientName": "",
          "isChecked": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "productTypeCounter": [
    {
      "centralCostID": 1,
      "centralCostName": "Refrescos",
      "sellUnit": 280,
      "cNomina": 0.0000
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using something like this

```
String addMore = '${detail}';

def detail = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(addMore);

detail.put(deposito);

vars.put("detail", new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(detail).toPrettyString());

log.info("",vars.get('detail'));
```

The log shows the following error

```
020-09-23 09:09:25,857 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.put() is applicable for argument types: (org.apache.groovy.json.internal.LazyMap) values: [[settlementTransactionID:11, settlementTransactionDescription:11 Deposito de Efectivo, ...]]
Possible solutions: sum(), pop(), get(int), get(int), sum(java.lang.Object), plus(java.lang.Object)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:71) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:89) ~[java.scripting:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:222) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.extractor.JSR223PostProcessor.process(JSR223PostProcessor.java:45) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPostProcessors(JMeterThread.java:940) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:572) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.put() is applicable for argument types: (org.apache.groovy.json.internal.LazyMap) values: [[settlementTransactionID:11, settlementTransactionDescription:11 Deposito de Efectivo, ...]]
Possible solutions: sum(), pop(), get(int), get(int), sum(java.lang.Object), plus(java.lang.Object)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:70) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:46) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at Script158.run(Script158.groovy:31) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:317) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot help you as it's unclear what are these `${detail}` and `${deposito}` mean and contain.

If you get a `deposito` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which looks like:

```
{
  "settlementTransactionID": 2,
  "settlementTransactionDescription": "2 Envase Faltante",
  "charge": 0.0,
  "payment": 7500.0000,
  "isAutomatic": true,
  "isForClient": false,
  "isCharge": false,
  "isChecked": false,
  "settlementTransactionClientDetail": [
    {
      "settlementTransactionID": 3461,
      "clientID": 0,
      "saleNote": null,
      "amount": 7500.0000,
      "reference": "202|75.00|100.000",
      "clientName": "",
      "isChecked": false
    }
  ]
}
```

and you want to add it to the response of a certain sampler and store the result into another JMeter Variable you can use [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) with the following code:

```
def originalResponse = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
originalResponse.detail.add(new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('deposito')))
vars.put('modifiedResponse', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(originalResponse).toPrettyString())
```

assuming everything goes well you will get the JSON payload you're looking for in the `${modifiedResponse}` JMeter Variable.

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thank you so much.
Sorry, I didn't really explain 'deposito', that contains the other node as you exemplified